# PHPmailer and boundary headers

Tags: phpmailer, mime, boundary

Is it possible to add/update boundary headers via PHPmailer for the code

`$mail->addStringAttachment($test, 'test.txt', 'quoted-printable');`

I need to add/update

```
--b1_KyZbvbrSl55hdWoQf7uUOwdfF2oGjqnCyP6rqNmlA
Content-Type: text/plain; name="test.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt
```

to looks like

```
--b1_KyZbvbrSl55hdWoQf7uUOwdfF2oGjqnCyP6rqNmlA
Content-Type: text/plain; name="test.txt"; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt
Content-ID: 20cca107-2625-49ce-9357-95254a59147f@127.0.0.1
```

so for the `Content-Type` header was added `charset` parameter and then added new header `Content-ID`

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation it came up that

> The addStringEmbeddedImage method lets you set a cid for the
>   attachment which will set that header for you. You can ignore the
>   "image" in the method name - it doesn't care what type of content you
>   attach really.

So in my case it will be

`$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage(file_get_contents($file_name, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH), $uuid, $file_name, 'base64', '', 'attachment');`

Regarding adding `charset` parameter to the `Content-Type` boundary header

> quoted-printable transfer encoding is ASCII 7bit safe, so the default
>   will work fine and it doesn't need an extra charset clause.

Answer (score 0):

For transfer-encoding and charset

```
$mail->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

For content-id check addEmbeddedImage method or try adding directly the header like this:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-ID', '20cca107-2625-49ce-9357-95254a59147f@127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: I'm looking for setting up headers for each boundary not message itself.

Comment: Well, kind of but getting close.